# How to set radius of RotateAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation

I am able to rate an image pointing to center of the screen. But it rotates in big radius, partially keeps off the screen. How to set radius like say 100 px.

```
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

    screenWidthPixel = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeightPixel = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

    center_x = screenWidthPixel/2;
    center_y = screenHeightPixel/2;

    //RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.ABSOLUTE, center_x, Animation.ABSOLUTE, center_y);
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, center_x, center_y);
    rotate.setDuration(2000);
    rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

    ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_img);

    image.setAnimation(rotate);
```

I am looking something like `rotate.setRadius(100)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Remove *center_x, center_y* parameters from `RotateAnimation()` and instead set `ImageView` in center of the screen in `layout.xml`.

**Activity.java**

```
 RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360);
 rotate.setDuration(2000);
 rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
 rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
 ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_img);
 image.setAnimation(rotate);
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test_img"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Here the img will rotate itself in the center if I put android:layout_centerInParent="true" I want the img to be rotate centering the center point of screen with say 100 px radius